# Can't login in AngularJs iframe within Non-Angular Application-Protracor

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have tried lots of suggestion from stackoverflow already addressed this kind of issue but couldn't make it work.
Using latest chrome and driver in Windows env.
Can experts step up and address my issue? Really apprecaite.

```
describe('tutorial point non-angular to angular frame login', function() {
var username = element(by.id('username'));
var password = element(by.id('password'));
var loginform = element(by.id('form'));
beforeEach(function() {
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.get('https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_login_application.htm');
browser.manage().window().maximize();
}); 

it('should be to switch non-angular to angular iframe and login', function(){
    //var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    //browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('iframe.result')), 20000);
    //browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
    browser.switchTo().frame(0);
    //browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css('iframe.result'))); // switching to angular iframe
    //browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); 
    //browser.waitForAngular(); 
    //browser.sleep(4000);
    //browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(username), 20000);
    username.sendKeys("test");  // tried xpath, css-selector, but no luck, 
                                // probably iframe is not recgnised as AngularJs enabled           
});
});
```

> ```
> ERRR:   
> Message:
> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="username"])
> Stack:
> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, * 
> [id="username"])
>
> HTML: Please refer to URL as it is public
> ```

Note: Using python and selenium, it works fine with same locators. I suppose locator is not issue.

Comment: I opened that url and there are 39 iframe on the page,  and the first frame is not the frame include the login form.  So `browser.switchTo().frame(0);`  did not switch to the correct frame.  I suspect the amount of iframe on the page will not same on each opening the url, because many iframe are used for advertisement,  for different person seems the page will display different advertisements.

Comment: True there. Its was not my interest to have solution rather to get logic straight. My code worked switching to right frame. Thanks you GREAT YONG!!

Comment: Sorry I can't up vote comment as I don't have enough points

Comment: Thanks to Uma for giving post a nicer look and Iinfern0 for providing an alternative approach. By the way, is it necessary to use call back if you use async/await?

Answer (score 0):

I have done experiment on toolsqa website.
Here is the test, hope it helps. Just adapt it to your needs.

```
 it('should dummy', async (done) => {
        let b = element(by.xpath('//a[text()=\'Hello world!\']'));
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await browser.get('http://toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/');


        await browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('IF2')).getWebElement());
        console.log('expecting element frame.');
        expect(await b.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        done();
    });
```